# How to create word in and out animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create text typing effect in react. I want to display different text at some time interval. I want to create effect like [this](https://thefront.maccarianagency.com/home).

> See the home page text below `A modern design system for your new`. Here i don't want to create typing effect, insted i want to animate word .

**My code*** :

```js
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text,setText] = useState(1);
  setInterval(()=>{
    if(text==1) setText(2)
    else if(text==2) setText(3)
    else setText(1)
  },5000)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>See me  {text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is code sandbox [live](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Sandbox link appears to be broken

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the ReactJsTyping NPM package. Add it to your workspace using `npm i reactjs-typing-effect`. Then you can do something like this:

```
import ReactJsTyping from 'reactjs-typing-effect';

const listOfString=['Reactjs Typing','custom speed'] // your list of words
const TypingComponent = () => { return (
  <div style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#2196F3'}}>
      <ReactJsTyping StringList={listOfString} speed={500}/> {// where the typing effect happens}
  </div>
    ) }
```

Comment: I can do much more than this with the packages, but why  this is not working.